# non-homogenous linear recurrence relation general questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

1. what happens if you have both repeated and non-repeated roots? i know there are different forms for both, so if given roots say $5, -3, -3, -3$ would it then be $A(5)^n + B(-3)^n + Cn(-3)^n + Dn^2 (-3)^n$?
2. since $a(n) = b(n) + p(n)$ for non homogenous recurrence relations, if this was your RR (e.g. $a(n) = 5(n-2) + (n-3) + 3(n-4) + 4*5^{n-2}$ how would p(n) look? would it look like $p(n) = 4Bn(5)^{n-2}+4C(5)^{n-2}$ (since 5 along with 3, 3, 3 is a root of the equation)?

i get quite confused about the p(n) part of a(n) = b(n) + p(n)
especially with the whole guessing part

sorry in advance for the formatting (i don't know how to use latex and this is my first post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct.

I’m guessing that in the second question you meant to write

$$a(n)=5a(n-2)+a(n-3)+3a(n-4)+4\cdot5^{n-2}\;,$$

so that the non-homogeneous part is just $4\cdot5^{n-2}$. However, in that case the roots of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous part are not $5,3,3$, and $3$. If you *did* have a homogeneous part whose characteristic equation had those roots, however, then $p(n)$ would have the form $B\cdot5^nn^1=Bn5^n$.

The general rule here is that if the non-homogeneous part has the form $r^nQ(n)$, where $r$ is a root of multiplicity $m$ of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous part, and $Q(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, then

$$p(n)=n^mr^n\left(p_0+p_1n+\ldots+p_dn^d\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

In your problem $r=5$, $m=1$, and $4\cdot5^{n-2}=\frac4{5^2}\cdot5^n=\frac4{25}\cdot5^n$, so $Q(n)=\frac4{25}$, and $d=0$.

If $r$ is not a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous part, leave out the factor of $n^m$ in $(1)$. (Equivalently, view the multiplicity of $r$ as $0$, and note that $n^0\equiv 1$.)

Comment: thanks for answering

in $ p(n) = 4/25 * 5^n $, would that then be the final value of p(n) so afterwards you just add that to the end of the homogeneous general solution, and then you can work on getting values with a given initial condition?

Comment: @anon: No, $p(n)=Bn5^n$, where $B$ still has to be determined. $\frac{4}{25}\cdot 5^n$ is $Q(n)$, the non-homogeneous part of the recurrence.

Comment: So does that mean for the non homogenous part to become $p(n)$ you disregard the coefficient 4? Where did the exponent -2 go? I just don't particular understand how you went from the homogenous part $4*5^n-2$ to $Bn5^n$ (I understand what B is)

Comment: @anon: I first rewrote the non-homegenous part as a polynomial times $5^n$: $4\cdot5^{n-2}=\frac4{25}\cdot5^n$. The polynomial, which I called $Q(t)$ in my answer, is the $0$-degree (constant) polynomial $\frac4{25}$. (In my previous comment I accidentally included the factor of $5^n$; that was an error.) When you set up $p(n)$, nothing about $Q(n)$ matters except its degree, which in this case is $0$; the specific coefficients (here just $\frac4{25}$) are irrelevant. One factor of $p(n)$ will be an unknown polynomial of degree at most $d$; here that’s $B$. Another will be $r^n$, here ...

Comment: ... $5^n$. And the last will be $n^m$, where $m$ is the multiplicity of the root $r$; here that’s $1$. Thus, we end up with $Bn5^n$.